# values in Property file values note geting loaded in ant from linux

Tags: linux, ant, properties

I am executing ant build from Linux machine. The whole works fine in Windows.
But in Linux, the values from property files are not getting loaded.

I am using the command **ant -Dpropertyfile=configurable.properties build** and also using

**property file = "build.properties"**

It doesn't return any values.

Also, is there any difference in executing ant build from Windows and Linux ?
Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant command line option to load a Properties file is `-propertyfile`. There is no `-D` before it nor an equals sign after it:

```
ant -propertyfile configurable.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ant command line option for loading the properties is -propertyfile <.properties> is for linux. There is no need for a equals or -D.